# Simplify failing to remove Conjugate

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

Let's take the following example code:

```
$Assumptions = {Element[{a,b,c},Reals]};
Simplify[Conjugate[a]]
Simplify[Conjugate[b]]
Simplify[Conjugate[c]]
Simplify[Conjugate[a*c]]
Simplify[Conjugate[b*c]]
Simplify[Conjugate[a+I*b]]
Simplify[Conjugate[a*c+I*b]]
Simplify[Conjugate[a+I*b*c]]
```

which generates the output:

```
a
b
c
a c
b c
a - I b
-I b + a c
Conjugate[a + I b c]
```

Why is Mathematica unable to simplify the last expression to `a - I b c`?

What is an appropriate and general solution to simplify conjugate expressions given some assumptions?

Further more: Why does Mathematica's simplification behave in that way?

Mathematica version under use: 11.0.0

Comment: `Conjugate[a + I*b*c] // ComplexExpand`

Comment: `Simplify` and `FullSimplify` *don't guarantee anything*. They try to apply some transformation, which may or may not produce a simpler form within a time limit. FullSimplify tries more kinds of transformations than Simplify. It does look like ComplexExpand is the appropriate function if you need this *specific* transformation.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Addition and multiplication are quite easy functions to iterate on. The only way my example could fail is that the recursion fails to iterate on simple additions/multiplications. This behavior seems pretty random. So it's either buggy or badly implemented. The question then is: How to catch those issues in a way that can still handle generale assumptions (which ComplexExpand cannot). Sure I propably could just go down the brute-force-road `FullSimplify[Simplify[Refine[ComplexExpand[...]]]]` but that shouldn't be the solutions for terms containing "+,-,*,/".

Comment: I don't think this is a very well formulated question.  If you want to achieve a *specific* goal, you should state that goal clearly.  Reading your comments, that goal seems to just keep shifting and shifting. Are `a`, `b`, `c`, etc. real or not?  First you said real, then you said complex in a comment, without saying what output you expect in that case.

Comment: @Szabolcs: a,b,c real as always throughout that question. Goal 1) Understand why simplification of `Conjugate[a+I*b*c]` doesn't work (first question). Goal 2) Get a simplification method that works consistently with `Conjugate[]`, +,-,*,/ and assumptions (second question). Goal 3) Understand mathematicas simplification skeems in order to avoid buggy code without printing and debugging every simplification statement (question 3).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `FullSimplify`.

```
$Assumptions = {Element[{a,b,c},Reals]};
FullSimplify[Conjugate[a + I*b*c]]
```

> a - I b c

Comment: Nope. Not general enough. Compare `FullSimplify[Conjugate[a + I*b + d]]` and `FullSimplify[Conjugate[a + I*b*c + d]]`

Comment: @Marcel `FullSimplify[Conjugate[a + I b c + d]]` produces `a - I b c + d` and `FullSimplify[Conjugate[a + I*b + d]]` produces `a - I b + d`

Comment: No it doesn't with a,b,c real and d unrestricted and/or complex: [click](http://i.imgur.com/zE2sSaF.png)

Comment: @Marcel You are right!. For such situations where `a`, `b`, `c` and  `d` are not specified, then maybe `ComplexExpand` is the right choice as suggested by others. But in your question "...given some assumptions" that's why i suggested `FullSimplify`.

Comment: @Marcel, note that `ComplexExpand[]` can be fed a second argument telling which variables should be assumed complex, after which it assumes every other variable to be real: `ComplexExpand[Conjugate[a + I*b*c + d], d]`.

Answer (score 3):

I think the reason that the example `Conjugate[a+I b c+d]` doesn't work with the FullSimplify method is that the default `ComplexityFunction` gives your desired output the same complexity as the input. Consider:

```
LeafCount[Conjugate[a+I b c+d]]
LeafCount[a+I b c+Conjugate[d]]
```

> 10
>
> 10

I think what you want here is to have an output where the arguments to any Conjugate are as simple as possible. To do this one could come up with a custom `ComplexityFunction` as follows:

*edited slightly*

```
conjugateComplexity[expr_] := Total @ Cases[
    expr,
    Conjugate[a_]:>LeafCount[a],
    {0, Infinity}
]
```

Using this `ComplexityFunction` we get:

```
FullSimplify[
    Conjugate[a+I b c+d],
    ComplexityFunction->conjugateComplexity,
    Assumptions->Element[{a,b,c},Reals]
]
```

> a-I b c+Conjugate[d]

*Using TransformationFunctions and Simplify*

If we want to get the same behavior using Simplify, we need to add an additional function(s) to TransformationFunctions. Here is a function that expands out Conjugate objects:

```
expandConjugate[expr_] := expr /. Conjugate[a_Plus] :> Conjugate /@ a
```

Including this function in TransformationFunctions accomplishes what you want:

```
Simplify[
    Conjugate[a+I b c+d],
    ComplexityFunction->conjugateComplexity,
    TransformationFunctions->{Automatic, expandConjugate},
    Assumptions->Element[{a,b,c}, Reals]
]
```

> a-I b c+Conjugate[d]

Possibly there are cases where you might want to apply identities involving Power/Times as well.

Comment: Could this or something similar also be the case for the behavior of `Simplify[Conjugate[a+I*b*c]]`? i.e. mathematica thinks that the base expression is as complex as the wanted one?

Comment: @Marcel, that certainly is an experiment you can try yourself: evaluate the `LeafCount[]` of both your original expression and the purported "simpler form"; if the count of the latter is the same as or higher than the former, well...

Comment: @J.M. it's not the case for `Simplify[...]`